# Convert code binding to XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Have hard time converting following code to XAML:

```
var b2 = new Binding("Toggled") { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self) };
button.SetBinding(ButtonBase.CommandParameterProperty, b2);
```

Tried:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Toggled, RelativeSource=Self}"
```

But this doesn't work, "Relative source does not support converting from a string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Toggled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

[See this page in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but it should be {RelativeSource Self}

Comment: No, it should be `CommandParameter="{Binding Toggled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` as in link he posted

Comment: @ChrisW. - same here :)